# Hooking after get_header()

Tags: hooks

Does anyone know a good way to hook just after get_header() without hacking the theme? I know you can hook before the function loads header.php but I am trying to insert some HTML just after get_header() is finished.

Answer (score 3):

I hate answering questions in the negative because it is easy to go wrong, but there is no core hook that does that-- at least no hook that I have ever seen. I admit it could be handy for a couple of things though.

[`wp_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) loads the theme's header file. That is about it. It is really just an amped-up `include`. [If you look at the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L24), there is a hook that runs before the header file is loaded, but not one after.

It is possible that your theme has provided a hook though. I am thinking that that is the only chance you have of this working.

You could do this with Javascript, if that is an option, then you could hook the script to `wp_head` and wouldn't need to hack the theme. That is, you could load Javascript into the page `<head>` using the `wp_head` hook, and that Javascript could insert your HTML into the page body. It is not a great solution but given your condition about not editing the theme and given that there are no hooks you can rely on across multiple themes, that is the best I can think of.

Comment: +1. `wp_head` is the correct template action to use to add HTML to the document head. If the intent is to add content to the document **body**, then you'll have to wait for Twenty Thirteen, which will include standard template hooks.

Comment: Standard template hooks? I am intrigued.